# Is it necessary to explicitly indicate association part by joining in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was helping my friend with a training task. The method is below.

There are two entities: *User* and *Car* which are associated with one-to-one relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
//

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Car car;
```

Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
private User user;

@Override
public User getUserByAutoName(String name) {
   User user = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("SELECT u from User u JOIN Car c on u.id = c.id where c.name = :n", User.class)
        .setParameter("n", name)
        .getSingleResult();
return user;
```

As I know, we don't have to explicitly indicate the association part:

```
on u.id = c.id
```

Hibernate does it under the hood for us. But in this example when I don't do it, it ruins.
Can u please help to clear this moment? :)

Comment: Can you just add the declaration of entities ?

Comment: Test what I suggested in the comment

Comment: Ok, but question is when we have to do it explicily, in which relationships types and when we can drop it

Comment: You have the choice to work with native SQL or take advantage of the HQL language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your **User** @Entity specifies a [@JoinColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) on the *id* column of your **Car** entity, you don't need to specify the join criteria explicitly in the query itself. If you had not specified a @JoinColumn you would have had to make the join criteria explicit in the query itself.

The @JoinColumn annotation indicates a primary/foreign key relationship between the entities. Interestingly, the Hibernation [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) does not provide explanatory info on how to use it.

Can you provide the example where you don't specify the association? I don't see it in your question. Either way, I'd suggest trying this for your .createQuery:

```
...
 .createQuery(
  "SELECT u 
   from User u 
   join u.car c 
   where u.name = :n", User.class)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't precise which field should be use as reference for the join. Assuming your `User` class has a field named `@OneToOne Car car` you should try this query instead :

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.car as c WHERE c.name = :n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
User user = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("SELECT u from User u JOIN u.car as car where car.name = :n", User.class)
    .setParameter("n", name)
    .getSingleResult();
```

because Car is an attribut in the User entity